# What encoding does the "exec" function assume?

Tags: python, unicode

When you call Python (2.7+) "exec" function, what assumptions, or actions, does it take with regard to decoding the provided string input?

(By way of comparison - if you want a source .py file in your project to contain unicode, you have to embed a "magic sequence" in the top of the file.)

What I've noticed is that exec seems to be okay with finding unicode in the string input, even though I don't try to indicate an encoding anywhere.

For example, I can pass this string through exec:

```
my_string = "That will cost you ¥ 800.00"
```

and the resultant my_string variable produced by exec will indeed have the Yen symbol in it. So it *appears* exec is assuming utf-8?

Michael

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the [The Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec):

> The first expression should evaluate to either a Unicode string, a Latin-1 encoded string, an open file object, a code object, or a tuple.

It appears as though the `str` are encoded based on the native system, although characters less than 127 can be passed of as utf-8 characters; sometimes with funny encoding results.

Comment: The ref you cited that it says it can be a "unicode string"... but it doesn't mention a specific encoding. I guess that means it's not really "decoding" the string per se.. it's probably just retaining whatever bytes it finds in the input string.. whatever encoding those bytes might represent. That's my hypotehsis anyway :)

Comment: In this case, I don't think Python used Unicode, since ¥ is part of Latin-1 as code value 165.

Comment: It took me some time to do tests, but I have to tell you that this answer is wrong at least for Python 2.7.3 . And I confirm that UTF8 or latin1 for  ¥ is `\xa5` or `\u00a5` code 165 or 0xa5.

Comment: Agreed as per the comments, although I haven't edited my question.

Answer (score 5):

`exec` parses byte strings the same way as Python reads script files.

For Python 2.1–2.7 (as per [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)) that means you get ISO-8859-1 by default but you can change it using a coding-comment:

```
>>> exec 'print [hex(ord(c)) for c in u"\xC2\xA5"]'
['0xc2', '0xa5']

>>> exec '# coding=iso-8859-1\nprint [hex(ord(c)) for c in u"\xC2\xA5"]'
['0xc2', '0xa5']

>>> exec '# coding=utf-8\nprint [hex(ord(c)) for c in u"\xC2\xA5"]'
['0xa5']
```

The encoding of the script file that is calling `exec` doesn't influence the encoding of the code inside the string. (However of course the outer script encoding does determine what bytes are in the string if you're writing non-ASCII characters directly.)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Python does not assume anything, and has not to. If you look at the [Python Language Reference v2.6](https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec), you read :

> The first expression should evaluate to either a string, an open file object, or a code object

what is also on my 2.7.3 manual. And doc for Python 2.7.10 does not explicitely state that anything has changed since 2.4 ...

I did some tests on a 2.7.3, writing non ascii characters in an encoded form to avoid the first interpolation.

If you use a simple string, it is interpreted *as is*. On a Latin1 system :

```
>>> exec "x = 'That will cost you \xa5 800.00'"
>>> x
'That will cost you \xa5 800.00'
>>> print x
That will cost you ¥ 800.00
```

On a CP850 system :

```
>>> exec "x = 'That will cost you \xbe 800.00'"
>>> x
'That will cost you \xbe 800.00'
>>> print x
That will cost you ¥ 800.00
```

... and `print x` is then wrong on both systems because neither of them is utf8 :-(

Things go different if the input string is unicode. In that case you will get an implicit UTF8 transformation : in both systems

```
>>> print u"That will cost you \u00a5 800.00"
That will cost you ¥ 800.00
>>> exec u"x = 'That will cost you \u00a5 800.00'"
>>> x
'That will cost you \xc2\xa5 800.00'
```

Of course if everything is unicode, all goes ok again on both systems :

```
>>> exec u"x = u'That will cost you \u00a5 800.00'"
>>> x
u'That will cost you \xa5 800.00'
>>> print x
That will cost you ¥ 800.00
```

If anyone here had a 2.7.10 to confirm or infirm that it would really be nice.

Comment: In my case, I'm populating python 2.7 str types from a text file containing utf8 characters, and thus ending up with strings such as: "a = '◀ unicode_test ▶'".   When I exec these, the unicode bytes making up those arrow symbols are "preseved" by exec. I am not prefixing "u" anywhere when reading in the file strings, or before exec'ing them.. I guess what I really want to know is if it's working in my case just because I'm getting lucky (ie default encodings along the way are helping me out) or if my approach is sound..

Answer (score -1):

`exec` assumes utf-8 unicode for str automatically. Once exce'ed string literals (except unicodes) gets encoded as UTF-8.